# Low code platform for data tranformation with pipeline exportable to general programming language

Tags: dataflow

Please name low or no code data tranformation platform(s), which means that a non or little technical (business) user can create data transformation pipeline using mostly GUI tool with semi-preconfigured activities like "read data" (from file, from connection string etc), "parse" (CSV to table), "filter", "sort", "transpose", "change values based on rules", etc.

And when pipeline is tested and ready, then export its activities to one (or more) general programming languages:

1. R
2. Python
3. Other

I could put up there some examples of no code platform - Alteryx, and low code platform - MS DataFactory (that I know), but they do not satisfy the second condition.